# How can I compute this sum without a for loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

In particular I'm interested in the summatory. It uses `k` two times, but using `sum` I don't know how to obtain the index.

Considering only the summatory:

```
summatory = sum( L(i, 1:j-1) * L(j, 1:j-1) );
```

is obviosly wrong.

How can I do it without a for loop?

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an inner product between an 1x(j-1) vector and a (j-1)x1 vector:

```
krange = 1:j-1;
summatory = L(i, krange) * L(j, krange)';
```

Your code would also have worked (now that you've fixed the syntax), if you used the element-wise product operator `.*` instead of the matrix product `*`.

Comment: I was just saying... :)

Comment: @chappjc: Yeah, I scooped you on `.*` by only about 3 seconds, nevermind what the timestamps say.  To be fair, though, the question originally had `L(k: 1:j-1)` or some such, which wasn't so fixable.

Comment: You keep the clever solution (or both), but I'm keeping the .* solution. Gotta give my fingers some recognition for their effort!

Comment: +1 but my usual quibble: what if the data is complex? You've inadvertently introduced a complex-conjugation with `'`

Comment: @LuisMendo: In such a case, conjugation is usually the right thing to do.  And if not, use a simple transpose.  Is there an operator for transpose (without conjugation), or call `transpose(y)`?  Ahh, `.'`

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually that's what I meant. `.'` vs `'` is one of my pet peeves :-)

Answer (score 3):

Either compute the inner product with vector algebra (i.e. v*v' as demonstrated by @BenVoigt), or use `sum`, but with the element-wise product (`.*`):

```
summatory = sum( L(i, 1:j-1) .* L(j, 1:j-1) );
```